# How to size empty image without affecting non-empty image?

Tags: html, css

I want to fix the size of empty image to `150px`. On Firefox, I can use `float: left`, but it doesn't work on Google Chrome.

HTML:

```
<div>
 <img src='some broken url' alt='no image'>
 <br>
 <img src='http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6063/6046604665_da6933bd10.jpg'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
    background: cyan;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    background: grey;
}
```

Is there a CSS solution for this?

I think there is some misunderstanding. The srcs are supposed to be random urls that I wouldn't know in advanced.

Comment: `img[src]
{
...
}` and leave out src if it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, use an empty placeholder `<div>` for this:

```
<div>
 <div><!----></div>
 <br>
 <img src='http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6063/6046604665_da6933bd10.jpg'>
</div>
```

... and give it the dimensions you need. This will allow you to do stuff like show a background placeholder image in its place etc.

Comment: But wouldn't this require some javascript? I wouldn't know if image is available beforehand to change the html element.

Comment: You'd just render it on server-side either as an image or as a div, no Javascript. But if this sounds too complex, I'd go with dop-trois' suggestion above.

Comment: But the urls are supposed to be random external links, i mean src='' to represent broken link. Have edited my question to make it clear.

Comment: @Ben Huh: In this case my suggested solution is not an option. You'll either have to stick with a broken <img> tag or test whether the image exists before rendering it. If I remember right, IE8 renders a broken image icon when the src is missing, possibly other browers.

Comment: Yes, Chrome shows a small icon too; Firefox doesn't. Anyway, thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style an empty image-tag:

```
img[src=""] { width: 150px; }
```

Should work, expect for IE6.

If you want to get it cross browser compatible, the solution from [@Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070760/how-to-size-empty-image-without-affecting-non-empty-image/11070783#11070779) would be your best choice.

---

Or jQuery solution (because CSS can't check for broken URLs):

```
$('img').error(function(){
    $(this).css('width', '150px');
});
```

Comment: Just in case it's important to the OP in this case, this attribute selector is not supported in IE6.

Comment: @Tom Thank you. I forgot to mention. Edited my answer.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding, the urls are supposed to be random.

Comment: @BenHuh In my opinion, this isn't possible with CSS only, because CSS can't check for broken image URLs. Do you accept a jQuery/Javascript solution?

Comment: Yes, I understand that CSS is not able to check for a broken link. I was wondering, since I have specified a `min-width` and a `max-width`, the image would have to be rendered within this range. If the image size is within this range, then it should be rendered as is. If the image is larger than `max-width`, then it should be rendered with width equal to `max-width`. If image is smaller than `min-width`, it should be rendered with width equal to `min-width`. If no image is found, I assume logically that it should keep with `min-width` since size would be 0.

Comment: @Ben huh: Yep, but I wouldnt assume browsers to respect width and height for an image that has a broken source. Even on Firefox, the image simply collapses on itself regardless of width and height defined.